# Python 3.4 - Add file name + line number to all files in a folder

Tags: python

I'm not a programmer and I've been doing my best to create some small scripts with **Python 3.4** that help me with different tasks at work.

I have several **.txt file**s and I to every line in the file I would need to append:

- the file name
- the file name+ line number
- **save it as a UTF-8 csv with all fields separated by commas**.

I managed to do this for one particular file, but I'm struggling to do it for all the files in the folder. I've tried `import glob` but with no success.

This is the code right now (a mess... that partially works):

```
with open('Ruth.txt', 'r') as program:
    data = program.readlines()

with open('Ruth.txt', 'w') as program:
    for (number, line) in enumerate(data):
        program.write('%d","%s' % (number + 1, line))
files = 'Ruth.txt'

all_lines = []
for f in files.split():
  lines = open(f, 'r').readlines()
  for line in lines:
    all_lines.append('"' + f + '"' + ',' + '"' + f + line.strip() + '"')

fout = open(f + 'out.csv', 'w')
fout.write('\n'.join(all_lines))
fout.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os

def add_numbers(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as readfile:
        data = readfile.readlines()
    with open(filename, 'w') as writefile:
        for i, line in enumerate(data):
            writefile.write('%d. %s' % (i + 1, line))

for path, _, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in filenames:
        add_numbers(os.path.join(path, filename))
```

This will add numbers to each file in the directory and each file in all sub-directories.  If you don't want it to check all sub-directories, change the `for` loop to this:

```
path, _, filenames = next(os.walk(folder))
for filename in filenames:
    add_numbers(os.path.join(path, filename))
```

Comment: Thanks Zondo! I get this error: for path, _, filenames in os.walk(folder):
NameError: name 'folder' is not defined

Comment: @Ruth you will need to specify your directory in os.walk argument (folder). More information here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm

Answer (score 0):

This will take all text files in current folder and turn them into utf-8 encoded 'csv-style' files so that space in the text is turned into a comma with filename and line number also comma-separated.

```
from glob import glob
filenames = glob("*.txt")

text = ''
for fn in filenames:
    with open(fn,'r') as f:
        for i,line in enumerate(f):
            line=','.join(line.split())
            text += ','.join((line,fn,i+1)) + '\n'
    fnew = fn.rsplit('.',1)[0]+'.csv'
    with open(fnew,'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(text)
```

Comment: thanks, I get TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (3 given).

Comment: right, try to put a parenthesis around. Will edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

here the complete script that take one positional argument (folder) and create a new .csv file at the same level than the file.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from pathlib import Path

def get_files(folder_path, suffix=".txt"):
    return Path(folder_path).glob("**/*%s" % suffix)

def write_lines(file_):
    with file_.with_suffix(".csv").open("w") as fout, file_.open(encoding="utf-8") as fin:
        for i, line in enumerate(fin, 1):
            # line number, file name, line
            new_line = ",".join(["%d." % i, file_.name, line])
            fout.write(new_line)

def main(folder):
    for file_ in get_files(folder):
        print(file_)
        write_lines(file_)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main(sys.argv[1])
    except IndexError:
        print("usage: %s foldername" % sys.argv[0])
```

Comment: Thanks Ali. I've tried it but it's giving me an error here: main(sys.argv[1]), IndexError: list index out of range. I changed it to 0 and nothing seems to happen. I'll keep trying and investigating.

Comment: just call it as _python thescript.py yourfolder_